Sending automated mail from a shared Gmail box via google form
Good day,  I have a script embedded in a google sheet that is linked to a Google Form. Everytime someone fills that form and sends it, it goes into this Google sheet and triggers the code to be run.
According to the answers provided in the form, the script will send an email to the group identified in the answers, on the behalf of the shared mailbox. The Google sheet resides on our team G Drive.
People filling the form may be from anywhere, always outside the members of the shared mail box. The form basically is to provide feed back to our centralized team, and we dispatch the info to the targeted service email.
I want the targeted service to receive the mail on the behalf of our shared mailbox name. My understanding of using Alias, is that the person running the script needs to have access (be member) of the shared mail box in order to use the alias to it. This can not be in this case for there is no way we will grant access to our shared mail box to the entire world (potentialy).
When I wrote in the past script for our team that would send email from our shared mailbox was not an issue. Each members of our team wanting to use the scripted needed to put the shared mailbox in alias.
At the moment, the MailApp is used for that, but the message received from the service is from the personal email of the person who created the Google Sheet (That is my understanding of why the email comes from that person personal mailbox).
I read that GmailApp should be used to send emails from a shared mailbox but I fail to find a way sround the usage of alias.
There must be a fix for that I fail to find.
For clarity, here is how the chain of event goes:
Google Form (opened to the world) -> sends data to Google sheet (on our protected group GDrive -> Script launched when new data is added to the Google Sheet from the form -> sends an email to an adress (at this point it is sent FROM the mail adress of the person who created the Google Sheet) -> makes a copy of the content of the email onto our protected group GDrive (files created are name to the same name from which email is sent).
Thank you for the help.
Note: I contacted our IT to try to help me but they seem clueless.
This is the snippet of code I use.  :)
 var EMAIL_TEMPLATE_DOC_URL = 'https://docs.google.com/document/d/1WVsqoAHOpynoZj1r1u5QdVfK3uuLLdg0B6vgWZ_3xCs/edit?usp=sharing';
var EMAIL_SUBJECT = 'SSPE-EPSR new item';
var DOC_TEMPLATE_ID = '1WVsqoAHOpynoZj1r1u5QdVfK3uuLLdg0B6vgWZ_3xCs'; // Document :  Employee Product Safety Reporting Notification
var DOC_FOLDER_ID = '1tdduiuHy5lF6alt5M1-AKT5e-ErpYgje'; // Folder :  SSPE/EPSR report

// The form used to submit data is : Master - Formulaire Sécurité Produit - Product Safety Form

/**
 * Installs a trigger on the Spreadsheet for when a Form response is submitted.
 */
function installTrigger() {
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('onFormSubmit')
      .forSpreadsheet(SpreadsheetApp.getActive())
      .onFormSubmit()
      .create();
}

/**
 * Sends a customized email for every response on a form.
 * 
 * @param {Object} event - Form submit event
 * e is the Google Sheet event from Form, detailled here after 
 * https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit
 */
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  var responses = e.namedValues;
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var recipient;
  var recipientsCC = "Shared_Mailbox@Domain.COM";
  var timestamp, email, language;
  var name;
  var organisation;
  var email_org;
  var title, location, model, msn, phasis, area, issue, impact, document, circonstance, date, pictures;
  
  /*
  var message = "";
  for(var field in e.namedValues) {
    message += field + ' :: ' + e.namedValues[field].toString() + "\n\n";
  */

  // If the question title is a label, it can be accessed as an object field.
  // If it has spaces or other characters, it can be accessed as a dictionary.
  timestamp = responses.Timestamp[0];
  email = responses['Email Address'][0].trim();
  language = responses['Choisir une langue / Choose language'][0].trim();
  
  /* check langage in order to pick the right question lang and the right answers */
  if( language == 'Français' )
  {
    /* Get each responses for language Français, and store it in dedicated variable */
    /* WARNING : take care that if text is modified directly in the google form, variable WILL not be updated */ 
    name = responses['Identifiez vous (Prénom, Nom)'][0].trim();
    organisation = responses['A quelle organisation appartenez vous?'][0].trim();
    email_org = vlookupscript(organisation, sheet.getSheetByName("data").getRange('B4:F25').getValues(),4 );
    title = responses['Titre du Rapport'][0].trim();
    location = responses['Quel est l\'endroit concerné?'][0].trim();
    model = responses['Quel est le modèle concerné?'][0].trim();
    msn = responses['Quels sont les produits concernés? (si applicable)'][0].trim();
    phasis = responses['Le problème est survenu lors d\'activités en: '][0].trim();
    area = responses['Où dans l\'usine le problème est-il survenu? (numéro de bâtiment, poste, zone...)'][0].trim();
    issue = responses['Description du problème rencontré'][0].trim();
    impact = responses['Quel est l\'élément affecté par ce problème ? (pièce, équipement, composant, sous-ensemble, installation, structure, système, fonction, performance...)'][0].trim();
    document = responses['Numéro de document de référence associé (Manuel, Processus, Procédure, Méthode, Instruction...)'][0].trim();
    circonstance = responses['Comment a été identifié le problème? (circonstances...)'][0].trim();
    date = responses['Date de l\'identification du problème?'][0].trim();
    pictures = responses['Avez-vous des photos, fichiers ou autres permettant de mieux comprendre votre signalement ?'][0].trim();
  }
  else
  {
    name = responses['Your Identification (Name, Surname)'][0].trim();
    organisation = responses['Which organization are you from?'][0].trim();
    email_org = vlookupscript(organisation, sheet.getSheetByName("data").getRange('C4:F25').getValues(),3 );
    title = responses['Report Title'][0].trim();
    location = responses['What is the location concerned?'][0].trim();
    model = responses['What is the Model at stake?'][0].trim();
    msn = responses['What are the products at stake? (if applicable)'][0].trim();
    phasis = responses['The issue found during activities in: '][0].trim();
    area = responses['Where in Plant this issue is a concern? (i.e. station number, building number, area ...)'][0].trim();
    issue = responses['Issue description'][0].trim();
    impact = responses['What is the issue impacting? (part, equipment, assembly, installation, structure, system, function, performance...)'][0].trim();
    document = responses['Related Document Number (Manual, Process, Procedure, Method, Instruction,,,)'][0].trim();
    circonstance = responses['How was the issue identified ? (circumstances...)'][0].trim();
    date = responses['When was the issue found?'][0].trim();
    pictures = responses['Do you have any pictures or data to share allowing us to better understand your report ?'][0].trim();
    
  }


  var emailcc // Names to be added to RecipientsCC as carbon copy

  emailcc = "Name1@domain.com, Name2@domain.com.com" // Email adress added
  recipient = email_org;
  recipientsCC = recipientsCC + "," + emailcc; // + "," + email;

  // If there is at least one topic selected, send an email to the recipient.
  var status = '';
  // Append the status on the spreadsheet to the responses' row.
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var row = sheet.getActiveRange().getRow();
  var epsr_nbr = manage_epsr_nbr(row); //sheet.getRange(row, 1).getValues();
  sheet.getRange(row, 1).setValue(epsr_nbr);

  var report_gdoc_ID = createEmailBody(epsr_nbr, timestamp, name, email, language, organisation, title, location, model, msn, phasis, area, issue, impact, document, circonstance, date, pictures);
  var emailBody = docToHtml(report_gdoc_ID);

  /* sauver le doc en créant un pdf  */
  var report_pdf = DocumentApp.openById(report_gdoc_ID);
  const pdfContentBlob = report_pdf.getAs(MimeType.PDF);
  var reportResponseFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(DOC_FOLDER_ID); 
  const newAnswrPDF = reportResponseFolder.createFile(pdfContentBlob).setName(epsr_nbr);


 /* Envoie le courriel  **/
  
  MailApp.sendEmail({   
    
    to: recipient,
    cc: recipientsCC,
    subject: EMAIL_SUBJECT,
    htmlBody: emailBody,
    attachments: [newAnswrPDF.getAs(MimeType.PDF)],
  });
  status = 'Sent';

  /* column AH is equal to 34 */
  var column = 34;
  // sheet.getRange(row, column).setValue('Sent Automatically');
  

  Logger.log("status=" + status + "; responses=" + JSON.stringify(responses));
}

function manage_epsr_nbr(row)
{
  var date = new Date();
  var yr = date.getFullYear();

  var nbr = row-1;
  //var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  //var row = sheet.getActiveRange().getRow();
  
  var epsr_nbr = "EPSR-" + yr + "-" + nbr; 
  
  //sheet.getRange(row, 1).setValue(epsr_nbr);
  return epsr_nbr;

}
/**
 * Creates email body and includes the links based on topic.
 *
 * @param {string} recipient - The recipient's email address.
 * @param {string[]} topics - List of topics to include in the email body.
 * @return {string} - The email body as an HTML string.
 */
function createEmailBody(epsr_nbr, timestamp, name, email, language, organisation, title, location, model, msn, phasis, area, issue, impact, document, circonstance, date, pictures) {
  
  // Make sure to update the emailTemplateDocId at the top.
  //var docId = DocumentApp.openByUrl(EMAIL_TEMPLATE_DOC_URL).getId();
  
  var templatefile = DriveApp.getFileById(DOC_TEMPLATE_ID);
  var reportResponseFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(DOC_FOLDER_ID);

  var copy = templatefile.makeCopy(epsr_nbr + ', ' + organisation, reportResponseFolder);

  var temp_gdoc = DocumentApp.openById(copy.getId());
  
  var body = temp_gdoc.getBody();

  body.replaceText("{{EPSRNBR}}", epsr_nbr);
  body.replaceText("{{TIMESTAMP}}", timestamp);
  body.replaceText("{{NAME}}", name);
  body.replaceText("{{EMAIL}}", email);
  body.replaceText("{{LANGUAGE}}", language);
  body.replaceText("{{ORGANISATION}}", organisation);
  body.replaceText("{{TITLE}}", title);
  body.replaceText("{{LOCATION}}", location);
  body.replaceText("{{MODEL}}", model);
  body.replaceText("{{MSN}}", msn);
  body.replaceText("{{PHASIS}}", phasis);
  body.replaceText("{{AREA}}", area);
  body.replaceText("{{ISSUE}}", issue);
  body.replaceText("{{IMPACT}}", impact);
  body.replaceText("{{DOCUMENT}}", document);
  body.replaceText("{{CIRCUMSTANCE}}", circonstance);
  body.replaceText("{{DATE}}", date);
  body.replaceText("{{PICS}}", pictures);
  
  temp_gdoc.saveAndClose();
  
  return temp_gdoc.getId();
}

/**
 * Downloads a Google Doc as an HTML string.
 * 
 * @param {string} docId - The ID of a Google Doc to fetch content from.
 * @return {string} The Google Doc rendered as an HTML string.
 * 
 * inspired from https://gist.github.com/slaporte/2db6cf05e19983d66f4cacb696d71e68
 */
function docToHtml(docId) {

  // Downloads a Google Doc as an HTML string.
  var url = "https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/documents/export/Export?id=" +
            docId + "&exportFormat=html";
  var param = {
    method: "get",
    headers: {"Authorization": "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()},
    muteHttpExceptions: true,
  };
  return UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, param).getContentText();
}

function vlookupscript(search_key, range, index) {
  var returnVal = null;
  for (var i in range) {
    if (range[i][0] == search_key) {
      returnVal = range[i][index - 1];
      break;
    }
  }
  return returnVal;
}

I tried using GmailApp in replacement of MailApp, and nothing happens. No email is being sent, but all other portions of the script to run, including making the HTML document and pdf.

Welcome to StackOverFlow! Please take this opportunity to take the tour and learn how to ask, format the code, create a minimal reproducible example, etc.

Please include all the Code so that we can check where to modify as well.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

This question is similar to: Sending automated mail from a shared mail Google Mail box. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Other related questions: How to use Google Script Send email with group account and Sending emails via google apps script from a different email?

Just trying to think of options... even though an email might be sent to the group from a user's personal account, have you considered including a Name parameter (such as, "Automated Group X mailer") to show that it is an email generated from the script?

Good suggestion, I will look at it.
